# Trying to reuse canvas with previous drawn items

Tags: android, canvas

I am drawing a rectangle in the canvas on the first attempt and again I am attempting to draw one more rectangle at a different position. When I finally add them to `LinearLayout` I see the only 2nd rectangle, the first rectangle is lost.

```
Bitmap place = Bitmap.createBitmap(400,800,Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(place);
DrawRect dr = new DrawRect();
dr.setLocation(10,10);
dr.draw(canvas);
dr.setLocation(10,80);
dr.draw(canvas);
ll.removeAllViews();
ll.addView(dr);
```

How do I make both the rectangles to be visible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem in the code, i should not use the same DrawRect object for drawing one more item, instead use the same but different DrawRect object does the magic.

Answer (score 0):

`removeAllViews()` will remove all view of `LinearLayout`.

You are adding view after `removeAllViews()` thats why you see 2nd rectangle only.

So remove this`ll.removeAllViews();` line and run again.

Comment: removeAllViews removes the views that were present in the past and not newly added.